# Strange neo4j-shell issue connecting to Neo4j in a docker instance

Tags: neo4j

I have a really strange problem connecting to a Neo4j instance running in a docker instance. But first things first, here is my set up:

Everything runs on a MacOS. I use boot2docker, so the actual Docker instances run in a VirtualBox. I am able to reproduce this issue with Neo4j 2.1.5 and with Neo4j 2.2.0-M04.
Additionally, I installed Neo4j locally via homebrew and it is version 2.1.7. It is installed to have a neo4j-shell available.
The docker instances are accessible from the outside via 192.168.59.104. The docker instance itself has a 172.17.0.x IP address.

The problem:
I try to connect with neo4j-shell like this: `neo4j-shell -v -host 192.168.59.104 -port 1337 -name shell`. After a couple of minutes, it fails with:

```
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Connection refused
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.17.0.2; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.welcome(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.sayHi(AbstractClient.java:215)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.findRemoteServer(RemoteClient.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.shell.ShellLobby.newClient(ShellLobby.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:297)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:175)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:120)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 14 more
```

The interesting part is, that it fails by trying to connect 172.17.0.2 instead of the provided IP address.

What I did so far:

- Double check neo4j.properties are correct

  - `remote_shell_host=0.0.0.0` is set
  - `remote_shell_port=1337` is set
- check the ports are exposed properly with `docker ps`:

  ```
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
  099cfd1b8018        daneroo/neo4j:latest   "/bin/bash -c /launc   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:1337->1337/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp   neo4j
  ```
- Some Google and SO searches, but without any success.
- Different neo4j versions and docker images
- Basic connection checks with `telnet 192.168.59.104 1337`. This is successful.
- Catch up with Mark Needham at todays neo4j meetup

So, do I miss something? In theory this should happen every time you can access the Neo4j through another IP address than the Neo4j instance can see (e.g. if you run a Neo4j instance at home on a machine with the IP 192.168.x.y and you try to access it via your public IP you have at this time).
Where is the client, running outside the Neo4j environment, getting the internal IP address from? Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: What's your Docker "run" command parameters? `docker ps` check ports that are exposed for the Neo4j image.

Comment: Thanks for your questions, Kenny Bastani. The port is exposed and I can access it from the outside. As described in the question, I can use telnet to connect to it. The problem is something on the protocol level I think.

I will add the output of `docker ps` in the question.

Comment: I just verified that this is a remoting bug and not likely resolvable without a code change. I would report this as an issue against the Neo4j GitHub project or look and see if one isn't already created.

Comment: Thanks Kenny Bastani. I'll check the bugs and open one, if needed,  with a reference to this question.

Comment: Looks like this behaviour was already described in a bug: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1432. The fix for the initial poster is not what we need, but I added a comment with a link to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to the RMI protocol that the shell uses to communicate with Neo4j.
Afaik RMI also uses some additional ports and it might redirect the initial request. there is a system property in Java that you might want to try to set in `neo4j-wrapper.conf`: `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.59.104`

see:

- http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98au/java/jdk1.2beta4/docs/guide/rmi/rmiNetworkingFAQ.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html

Comment: was this ever resolved? I'm attempting the same and am getting a *Connection refused* on port 1337 (I can connect on 7474 without issue).

I need to be able to run cypher from a file against a containerized neo and I can't

Comment: you can use `docker exec` to run the neo4j-shell within a container

Comment: or you can use this to load a cypher file via the http API https://github.com/johnymontana/LazyWebCypher

Comment: I've created a request for this to be fixed: https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/issues/29 - and yes, I can docker exec into it but then I have to figure out how to get my .csv files where the system can get at them