# Neo4j remote shell through vagrant issue

Tags: neo4j, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm running a Neo4j instance inside my Vagrant machine. I put these lines into `neo4j.properties` to start the server with the remote shell

```
remote_shell_enabled=true
remote_shell_host=0.0.0.0
remote_shell_port=1337
```

I start neo4j server with the command `bin/neo4j start`

After that, I use neo4j shell inside vagrant to connect to the remote shell and it works fine.

I forward the port 1337 to the host machine with this in the Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 1337, host: 9255
```

And then on my host machine (MacOS), I use the neo4j shell to connect to that server but I fail

```
$ bin/neo4j-shell -port 9255 -v
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Connection refused
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.2.15; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.welcome(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.sayHi(AbstractClient.java:254)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.findRemoteServer(RemoteClient.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.shell.ShellLobby.newClient(ShellLobby.java:178)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:302)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:179)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:124)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 14 more
```

The vagrant machine has no firewall and I'm still able to connect to the web interface

Comment: maybe similar thing like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974592/strange-neo4j-shell-issue-connecting-to-neo4j-in-a-docker-instance

Comment: seem similar, however, I tried to set the conf like the answer but no success

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Holy ##@**(* I got it working after 6+ hours! With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections. I'm not a networking wiz, but apparently neo4j could tell that port forwarded connections are non-local, and refused them. To fix, you need to configure your `neo4j.conf` file to accept non-local connections

```
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You also need to remove the 'advertised_address' from each connector,
# so that only the port is specified
# i.e. my conf file originally had dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=localhost:7472
# I changed it to dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7472

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7472

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=false
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
```

Of course, in addition to all of this you need to have port forwarding properly set up in your `vagrantfile`. Strangely, I found I needed to make sure I was sharing every port `neo4j` was broadcasting on (http, https, bolt) or else there were some intermittent connection issues with the web console. This all being said, I can now properly connect via `neo4j-shell`, `cypher-shell`, and the `web console`--all from my host machine.

**Original**

I'm running into a similar problem. In your case, the output error includes `Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".` The `bin/neo4j-shell` file is written in Java, I believe (or perhaps the shell it starts relies on Java). The host machine needs to have the java development kit (JDK) installed to run that command. Try installing the JDK and running it again.

This all being said, I *DO* have the JDK installed on my machine (now "1.8") and I'm running into a similar problem when I try and run `bin/cypher-shell` (which has replaced `bin/neo4j-shell`) from my host machine (a mac): `Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.` When I try and connect from within `vagrant`, I do not run into any errors. My `vagrantfile` contains `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 7687, host: 7687, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"`.

I'll also note that, while I can connect to the neo4j web interface within `vagrant`, I cannot connect to the web interface on my host machine (i.e. port forwarding doesn't seem to be working for anything `neo4j` related). I can connect to a rails app running within the same `vagrant box` from my host machine just fine, however. While I haven't tried it, I imagine I can indirectly access the `neo4j` database through my Rails app (since my Rails app is port forwarding correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Still I cannot fix this problem, but I find another work around so I will post it here. We can use an ssh tunnel to pretend that we are connecting to localhost from that server. Use ssh to execute the command directly from the remote host

`ssh user@host /path/to/neo4j-shell`

or if you are using vagrant

`vagrant ssh -c '/path/to/neo4j-shell'`